# SVG image element gets cropped when rotating

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have created a SVG element and a path within it. It's not rectangular and is an irregular shape. Now, I needed to add an image to it which user can drag around and will stay within the path element. So, I used fill to do that.

The issue is that when I rotate the element by adding some transform, the edge gets cut off.

```
<svg id="magic">
    <pattern id="logo" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="900" width="900">
        <image xlink:href="libs/streetview/img/blank.png" transform="rotate(90,40,20)" />
    </pattern>
    <path class="classic" d="M4,79 A85,82,0,0,1,94,8 L94,282 4,283 Z" fill="url(#logo)" />
</svg>
```

PS: That 900/900 is because I wanted a single image while fill was repeating it, that 900/900 makes sure the repeating pattern is too far away and not within user's viewport.

Comment: It is advisable in this kind of question to attach a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) reproducing the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of a `<pattern>` as like a canvas you are drawing onto.  Any parts of your image that get rotated off the top-left edge will be cut off.

I would suggest you use a `<clipPath>` instead.  You will be able to rotate your image to your hearts content.

Comment: Your answer helped me climb a huge mountain four years back, but looks like I never accepted the answer. Four years late, but i hope better late than never? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Paul would you be interested in a small SVG consulting job? Basically just need a module that allows a group of text/tspan elements to be edited inline and achieves pixel perfect vertical/horizontal alignment to the parent.

Comment: Happy to talk about it. You can email me at: my first and last name at gmail.